# Sql Issue with Survey results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a query returning this

```
member_id   question_variable                                  response_id label
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------
35          area                                               15          Sydney (Metro)
35          relationship_status                                8           Single
35          education                                          31          Bachelor Degree
35          house_hold_income                                  4           $75,001 to $100,000
35          pets                                               36          Dog
35          pets                                               37          Fish
```

How do i detect duplicate results such as pets and have response_id = 36,37 and label = Dog, Fish
like so

```
member_id   question_variable                                  response_id label
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------
35          area                                               15          Sydney (Metro)
35          relationship_status                                8           Single
35          education                                          31          Bachelor Degree
35          house_hold_income                                  4           $75,001 to $100,000
35          pets                                               36,37          Dog,Fish
```

Comment: Please post both queries.  What problem are you having joining that information?

Comment: "How do i detect duplicate results". There could be multiple answers to this including simply looking at the results. Please be more specific about what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Please post expected result.

Comment: Updated the question. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Does response_id uniquely identify what's in label?  If so, do you need the response_id list order to match the label list order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the keyword **STUFF** to get the above result.

QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.MEMBER_ID,T1.QUESTION_VARIABLE,
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + T2.RESPONSE_ID
         FROM TEST T2
         WHERE T1.QUESTION_VARIABLE = T2.QUESTION_VARIABLE
            FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'') AS RESPONSE_ID,
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + T2.LABEL
         FROM TEST T2
         WHERE T1.QUESTION_VARIABLE = T2.QUESTION_VARIABLE
            FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'') AS LABEL         

FROM TEST T1
;
```

> **HERE IS THE LINK TO SQL FIDDLE** 
>   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64515/3

Comment: this works great... I just had to add t1.member_id=t2.member_id to the query group by member

Comment: This doesn't guarantee order if the response_id list needs to be in sync with the label list.

Comment: The fiddle seems empty!

Comment: @Nisha:I don`t see any issues with the link.It`s still working

Answer (score 1):

This is can be achieved in the following way as well. I haven't got a chance to test this against large data set. 
If you want to check the performance, please turn on the following

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT  Main.member_id,
        Main.question_variable, 
        STUFF(SubResponse.response_id,1,1,'') AS response_id,
        STUFF(SubLebel.label,1,1,'') AS label
FROM Member Main
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT  ',' + response_id 
    FROM Member 
    WHERE member_id = Main.member_id AND question_variable = Main.question_variable
    FOR XML PATH('')
) SubResponse (response_id)
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT  ',' + label 
    FROM Member 
    WHERE member_id = Main.member_id AND question_variable = Main.question_variable
    FOR XML PATH('')
) SubLebel (label)

GROUP By Main.member_id,
         Main.question_variable,
         SubResponse.response_id,
         SubLebel.label
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT member_id, question_variable, count(*) 
FROM MyData 
GROUP BY member_id, question_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```